Excel 2016 - INDEX MATCH to return value based on smallest of multiple match results
Sorry, this is my first time posting. Hope I am able to explain clearly. Using Excel 2016. Hi, I have data as seen below, and I want to return the date based on the smallest of the matches returned.



1
Column A
Column B
Column C




2
date
stock
amount


3
05/25/24
242000
100.00


4
05/26/24
242001
200.00


5
05/27/24
242002
300.00


6
05/28/24
242000
400.00


7
05/29/24
242000
-100.00


8
05/30/24
242001
200.00


9
05/30/24
242001
250.00


10
05/31/24
242000
150.00



Match Value: Stock # 242000
=INDEX($A$3:$C$10,MATCH(242000, $B$3:$B$10, 0), 1)

This formula should return date 05/25/2024, since it is the first match result for that stock number. I need a formula that will return 05/29/2024, because that is the match for  that stock number based on the lowest amount for that stock number in column C (Amount).
I think I am looking for an index match with multiple criteria the first being matching the stock #, the second being the lowest value for that stock number.
I have looked for a formula that will get me here, but haven't been able to find one. Please help!
Thanks so much!

Try using AGGREGATE() function: =AGGREGATE(15,7,C2:C9/(B2:B9=242000),1) or =MIN((B2:B9=242000)*C2:C9) or =SMALL((B2:B9=242000)*C2:C9,1) to get -100

Or, if you want the corresponding date returned: =INDEX(A2:A9, MATCH(1,(--(B2:B9=F2))*(--(C2:C9=MINIFS(C$2:C$9,B$2:B$9,242000))),0))

Ok, sorry i misunderstood the query: if date is needed then: =AGGREGATE(15,7,A2:A9/(C2:C9=AGGREGATE(15,7,C2:C9/(B2:B9=242000),1)),1) and format the cells as Date

@cybernetic.nomad sir MINIFS() works with Excel 2019+ onwards. SMALL() or MIN() then: =INDEX(A2:A9,MATCH(1,(MIN((B2:B9=242000)*C2:C9)=C2:C9)*(B2:B9=242000),0)) or =INDEX(A2:A9,MATCH(1,(SMALL((B2:B9=242000)*C2:C9,1)=C2:C9)*(B2:B9=242000),0))

@MayukhBhattacharya Don't have 2016 handy to test and I have a memory like a steel sieve. remembered it wrong, thank for pointing it out.

=INDEX(A3:A10,MATCH(1,(MINIFS(C3:C10,B3:B10,242000)=C3:C10)*(B3:B10=242000),0)) oops, I just read it's not compatible to Excel 2016 AGGREGATE is the way then, like @MayukhBhattacharya commented

As posted in comments try the following formula using AGGREGATE() twice:


• Formula used in cell E2
=AGGREGATE(15,7,A2:A9/(C2:C9=AGGREGATE(15,7,C2:C9/(B2:B9=242000),1)),1)


Or, Can use with MIN() or SMALL() with the help of INDEX()+MATCH()
=INDEX(A2:A9,MATCH(1,(MIN((B2:B9=242000)*C2:C9)=C2:C9)*(B2:B9=242000),0))


Or,
=INDEX(A2:A9,MATCH(1,(SMALL((B2:B9=242000)*C2:C9,1)=C2:C9)*(B2:B9=242000),0))


NOTE: Formulas using MIN() or SMALL() would require to hit CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER while exiting the edit mode.


Hi! Thank you so much @Mayukh Bhattacharya. The array formula using MIN is working almost perfectly, however it only seems to work if the amount is negative - if it is a positive I get an error. Any thoughts?

@JessicaSmith add an IF() function: =INDEX(A2:A9,MATCH(TRUE, MIN(IF(B2:B9=242000,C2:C9,""))=C2:C9,0)) btw there was an option, which is working accurately even if it is positive using AGGREGATE(), did you try that before asking?

@JessicaSmith it is not working because when we have positive vals and use only MIN() and perform a matrix product, it returns 0 as well, so it doesn't take the min value actual instead takes up the 0, therefore it returns an #N/A error while it doesn't happen with the AGGREGATE() function, you should have that tried that option btw i have posted in my earlier comment what you need to do!

@JessicaSmith hope this is resolved then please accept the answer by ticking the checkmark beside it so we can use your query as future reference and helps others as well. Thanks,!
